# Vinyl Tile Crackling Noise When Walking On It

Tags: flooring, vinyl-flooring

I recently installed standard self-adhesive vinyl tile in a section of my basement.  I cleaned the painted concrete and the surface was generally flat but it isn't perfectly smooth.  There were some small pock-marks and generally a little roughness to the surface.

When I walk on the tile now, it makes a bit of a crackling noise. I assume this is from small sections of the adhesive backing pressing down fully onto the floor and then lifting up it again.  Is there a simple method to fix this?

I see that some sites recommend you use a roller to push the tile down.  I didn't use one originally but I did shuffle my feet across the tiles to help assure they were pressed down fully.  Would a roller help?  It's been a few days since I installed it, so is it to late to try this?

Comment: Did you perform a slab moisture test prior to the install? Has the space been temperature controlled, with the tiles present in the room? When you say the floor was cleaned, was it mopped clean to remove all dust/dirt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the small voids below the tiles, if it was flat this would not be a problem a roller will do the same as walking on it, possibly heating with a heat gun may help but it may damage them as they actually need to melt a bit to drop down , if you want a pro job with no noise or problems the tiles will need to be removed and a leveling compound added, if it has not been long and you can get the same tiles you may be able to remove the bad areas , level and replace with new tiles, I was able to repair a large basement with a few areas that had problems because the owner had an extra box of the same type, I leveled the areas that had problems , applied the new tiles and it looked funny 4 areas that were lighter, I actually added some dirt and scrubbed it and the color was much better match. , if you don’t have some extra you may be able to get a close match and blend them in with some “dirty scrubbing” . Years back I used to think those tiles were a waste but if properly applied I have found them to hold up quite well in dry areas. If the noise bothers you or a few tiles come up try leveling then if needed a dirty scrubb.

Comment: Thanks.  I've got extra tiles so I'll try this.